# Handling "Value of type 'String' has no member" error with a dynamic variable in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my `UITableView`, I want to change an accessory icon based on if a file has been downloaded or not. I believe I am close; however, I am receiving an error that `Value of type 'String' has no member 'isDownloaded'`, which indicates that my attribute for whether the file was downloaded is not working.

First, I am instructing my `TableView` to check if a file has been downloaded:

```
   var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    if (TableData[indexPath.row]).isDownloaded {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }else {
        cell.accessoryType = .detailDisclosureButton
    }

    return cell
}
```

Of course, I need to establish a value for `isDownloaded` -- I try and do that here when the user clicks the accessory which starts a download.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {        
    if let audioUrl = URL(string: "https://rss.example.com.mp3") {

        // then lets create your document folder url
        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        // lets create your destination file url
        let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
        print(destinationUrl)

        // to check if it exists before downloading it
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
            print("The file already exists at path")

   // here's the error --> 
            (TableData[indexPath.row]).isDownloaded = true
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)

            // if the file doesn't exist
        } else {
            // ...   
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Adding a `var isDownloaded = false` before `viewDidLoad` did not help either. I am new to Swift -- is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: what arr TableData contains

Comment: `var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()` -- adding above.

Comment: string doesn't contains  isDownloaded property

Comment: Where do you get value for `TableData`

Comment: String is basic type in Swift, it doesn't and shouldn't contain custom property, in your case is "isDownloaded".You should create class or struct to keep data, for example: 
`class TableItem {
 var isDownloaded: Bool?
 var url: String?
}`
then you declare it like: 
`var TableData:Array< TableItem > = Array < TableItem >()`

Comment: TableData is an array of string. How would a string have isDownloaded property?

Answer (score -1):

```
let tableData = TableData[indexpath.row]
tableData.isDownloaded = true
TableData[indexPath.row] = tableData
```

Replace array object with current edited object.Then reload table in method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {        
if let audioUrl = URL(string: "https://rss.example.com.mp3") {

    // then lets create your document folder url
    let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    // lets create your destination file url
    let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
    print(destinationUrl)

    // to check if it exists before downloading it
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
        print("The file already exists at path")

  // here's the error --> 
    let tableData = TableData[indexpath.row]
    tableData.isDownloaded = true
    TableData[indexPath.row] = tableData

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)

        // if the file doesn't exist
    } else {
        // ...   
        }).resume()
    }
}
}
```

See edited answer

Comment: What is this? :)

Comment: How would this solve the `Value of type 'String' has no member 'isDownloaded'` error? – An answer is more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers) if you *explain* the problem and the solution.

Comment: TableData is an array of model classes.So it contains isDownloaded variable.